# cannot access global variable directly without referring global typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a global variable that can be accessed across the files,
below is the code

global.d.ts

```
declare module NodeJS {
interface Global {
  log: any;
 }
}

declare var log:any
```

index.ts

```
global.log = "Hello World"
console.log(global.log)//this Works
console.log(log) //this doesn't
```

tsconfig.json

```
 {


"compilerOptions": {                        
    "target": "es6",                         
    "module": "commonjs",                           
    "outDir": "./dist",                             
    "rootDir": "./src",                             
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,    
    "noImplicitAny": false 
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon ./src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/config": "^0.0.40",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.12",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

but for some reason

it is giving me the following error

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'log'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm pretty sure thats not how `global` works. If it actually worked like this, it could cause some pretty unpredictable behavior.

Comment: This could be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @VimalPatel I need 50 reputation to comment